# Integrate external form in Angular 6 component

Tags: javascript, angular, external

I've got third party questionary I want to integrate inside some component after several steps of logic in my website
I've got code like this:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript"
src = "https://thirdpartywebsite.com/forms/js.php/param_referral" >
  <
  /script> <
  noscript >
  <
  a href = "https://thirdpartywebsite.com/forms/param_referral"
title = "Online Form" > Online Form  < /a> <
  /noscript>
```

When I put it in index.html it shows of course , but disturbs the way the website looks .. 
It just pushes the code over.

How can I locate it in specific place in component?
Should I use only the noscript reference? The script is just pushing the code to the document.write line after line..

Answer (score 0):

you can't use external links in your components, but you can download that js file and import it in the component and use functions or variables from that code

Comment: That doesn't help.
They gave me some questionary exported from wordpress.
All I need is to add it as external iframe somehow.. 
I can maybe create an Iframe myself and put it there but it's not  an elegant solution